# What are the five armies in Hobbit: The Battle of Five Armies?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hobbit, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

*The Hobbit: The Battle Of The Five Armies* Movie tells about battle between five armies. I counted only four.

1. Dwarves Army (Lead by Throrin)
2. Elves army (Lead by Thranduil?)
3. Orcs army (Lead by Azog)
4. Lake Town people (Lead by Bard)(I think,this is not an army)

What is the fifth army. Please list the all five armies and its leaders?

Comment: See Sci-fi SE discussion [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75862/who-was-the-fifth-army-in-the-hobbit-the-battle-of-the-five-armies-movie) [**recap**: Worgs in the book, Orcs\Goblins from Gundabad in the film], though [some say](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Five_Armies) it's the Eagles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [LOTR Wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Five_Armies):

> The Battle of Five Armies was a battle waged between the Goblins and
>   the Wargs against Men of Dale, Elves, Dwarves, Eagles and a
>   Shape-shifter on and near the Lonely Mountain.[3]

The combatants are listed as:

> Thorin and Company, Dwarves from Iron Hills, Elves from Mirkwood, Men
>   from Lake-town, Great Eagles

Answer (score 2):

In the movie, the 5th Army is that of the Eagles lead by Thorondor.
This army is accompanied by Radagast and Beorn (in the form of a bear)

Comment: Can you explain why you think that (or provide proof\references)? Because, as I mentioned in my comment above, this issue seems to be in dispute at the moment.

Comment: Wargs in the movie are not treated a separate race of free thinking species. They are merely like horses are to men in the movie. Eagles however are shown to come to rescue many a times to the call of Gandalf. They are shown as an independent species and not merely large birds used for transportation. As far as the movie goes, the visuals are proof enough to count 5 armies. What's the dispute?

Comment: Did you read the thread I've linked above? (Also, I wrote that the Wargs are the 5th army according to the *book*). If you think the visuals prove it's the Eagles, that's great, but please explain why in your answer so we can upvote it. :)